# Navigation short cut between design and source pages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio, is there any keyboard shortcut possible to navigate between design and source pages of asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>F7</kbd> -> ViewCode
- <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> -> ViewDesigner

Found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

there is shortcut to See designer. <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f7</kbd> [KeyBorad Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx)

View Code : <kbd>F7</kbd>